# Adding a plugin to a partialview selectlist in MVC ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery function which loads a partialview into the HTML in a DIV:

```
function getRequest(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        context: document.body,
        success: function (data) {
            $('.modal-body p.body').html(data);
            $('#modalpop').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);

        }
    });
 }
```

This returns HTML, which includes a select list:

```
<select class="combobox" id="ItemId2" name="ItemId2">
  <option value="">Select item</option>
  <option value="1">item</option>
</select>
```

I want to add the Select2 plugin: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2 - to the SelectList.

Normally I would just use: `$('.combobox').select2();` but I'm not sure how to add it to the "new" list:

If I add within the getRequest(url) function:

```
    success: function (data) {
            $('.modal-body p.body').html(data);
            $('#modalpop').modal('show');
            $('.combobox').select2();
        },
```

...it is ignored.

Thank you for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

ignore me - I changed `$('.combobox').select2();` to `$("#ItemId2").select2()`

Mark